# Unable to boot into an extra drive I have connected to my system - Does not use dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have not used a computer of mine for a year.  I have 2 Linux OSs installed.  One is Arch on the main boot drive which boots fine and is the only option on the grub menu.  I also have Garuda installed for gaming.

My problem is that I cannot for the life of me remember how I used to boot into Garuda. I know that I had problems adding it to the grub menu, so I used a different, more hacky method.

Here is the `lsblk` of those drives:

```
sda           8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0   300M  0 part
└─sda2        8:2    0   1.8T  0 part
nvme0n1     259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   300M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 884.6G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0    69G  0 part [SWAP]
```

The filesystem cpmes up as `crypto_LUKS` when I try to mount it (and won't let me look at it).

I have been into the BIOS, but can only see the one boot drive.

What can I do to boot from this drive?

Thanks!!

Comment: What filesystem is your Garuda on? I remember a reddit post from about a year ago where they had it setup as Btrfs (the default for Garuda, IIRC) and needed to install os-prober-btrfs from the repo (and turn it on in /etc/default/grub)

Comment: I have installed Garuda 2 days ago. Looked in Octopi and 'os-prober-btrfs' is installed standard. From 'Grub2Win' in Windows and from 'Grub2' in Linux Mint I cannot boot into Garuda either. Before I had Kubuntu 20.04 ( on btrfs ) installed and had no problems. What works for me though is go into the UEFI bootmenu ( in my case pressing F9 ) and select Garuda there. It boots into Garuda no problem.